# React child component not fetching props and updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form that uses a child component with input fields. I have used props to get the data from the parent component, but it's not adding the prop value to the input field. There is no errors in the console.

Parent component:

```
const {
  address,
  errors
} = this.state;

return (
    <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
     <LocationInputGroup
        errors={errors}
        address={address}
     />

     <Button
        type="submit"
        style={{ marginRight: 10, marginTop: 20 }}
        variant="callToAction"
    > Submit</Button>
    </form>
);
```

Child component:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
     address: "",
     errors: {}
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            errors: this.props.errors,
            address: this.props.address
        });
}

render() {
  const {
    address,
    errors
  } = this.state;
  return (
    <div>
      <InputGroup
        value={address}
        error={errors.address}
        label="Address"
        name={"address"}
        onChange={e => this.setState({ address: e.target.value })}
        placeholder={"Address"}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

InputGroup component:

```
class InputGroup extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    //TODO check if scrolling still changes with number inputs
    //Bug was in Chrome 73 https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312
    //If it's no longer a bug these listeners can be removed and the component changed back to a stateless component
    handleWheel = e => e.preventDefault();

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.type === "number") {
            ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener("wheel", this.handleWheel);
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.props.type === "number") {
            ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).removeEventListener("wheel", this.handleWheel);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {
            disabled,
            classes,
            error,
            value,
            name,
            label,
            placeholder,
            type,
            isSearch,
            onChange,
            onBlur,
            onFocus,
            multiline,
            autoFocus,
            InputProps = {},
            autoComplete,
            allowNegative,
            labelProps
        } = this.props;

        if (type === "phone") {
            InputProps.inputComponent = PhoneNumberInputMask;
        }

        let onChangeEvent = onChange;
        //Stop them from entering negative numbers unless they explicitly allow them
        if (type === "number" && !allowNegative) {
            onChangeEvent = e => {
                const numberString = e.target.value;
                if (!isNaN(numberString) && Number(numberString) >= 0) {
                    onChange(e);
                }
            };
        }

        return (
            <FormControl
                className={classes.formControl}
                error
                aria-describedby={`%${name}-error-text`}
            >
                <FormatInputLabel {...labelProps}>{label}</FormatInputLabel>
                <TextField
                    error={!!error}
                    id={name}
                    type={type}
                    value={value}
                    onChange={onChangeEvent}
                    margin="normal"
                    onBlur={onBlur}
                    onFocus={onFocus}
                    InputProps={{
                        ...InputProps,
                        classes: {
                            input: classnames({
                                [classes.input]: true,
                                [classes.searchInput]: isSearch
                            })
                        }
                    }}
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    multiline={multiline}
                    autoFocus={autoFocus}
                    disabled={disabled}
                    autoComplete={autoComplete}
                    onWheel={e => e.preventDefault()}
                />

                <FormHelperText
                    className={classes.errorHelperText}
                    id={`${name}-error-text`}
                >
                    {error}
                </FormHelperText>
            </FormControl>
        );
    }
}

InputGroup.defaultProps = {
    value: "",
    type: "text",
    labelProps: {}
};

InputGroup.propTypes = {
    error: PropTypes.string,
    value: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    label: PropTypes.string,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
    type: PropTypes.string,
    isSearch: PropTypes.bool,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onBlur: PropTypes.func,
    onFocus: PropTypes.func,
    multiline: PropTypes.bool,
    autoFocus: PropTypes.bool,
    InputProps: PropTypes.object,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool,
    autoComplete: PropTypes.string,
    allowNegative: PropTypes.bool,
    labelProps: PropTypes.object
};

export default withStyles(styles)(InputGroup);
```

I hope someone can advise what the issue is and how to overcome it.

Comment: Your code looks ok. How `InputGroup` looks like?

Comment: Can you add the InputGroup component code, or are you using library ?

Comment: I have added the InputGroup component @Dupocas

Comment: I'm guessing the issue lies in the InputGroup component @DILEEPTHOMAS I never wrote this code. Just using what was provided.

Comment: Hi, there's a few things here you need to look at.  You are passing state from parent to child and assigning that in the child state.  You're also trying to handle state change in the child component by use of child state.  This is not the suggested approach.  From the parent you pass the state as props to the child (which you're doing), but you also need to pass the on-change event handler from parent to child too.  The react docs have really clear examples on how to do this.... https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: don't save parent prop in child state you can use it as it is.

Comment: Inisde InputGroup there is another component TextField where you are passing the value can you check that one whether the value is reaching at theTextField, normally you need to check at last an <input value={someProp} /> should be there also dont save the value in child so basically parent should take care of it that the normal approach

Comment: Ok if i understand properly, I should rather handle the setState in parent component? Not the child component.

Comment: Yes, handle state for all child components in the 'first common parent' component.  @Mukundhan has provided an example.  The React docs really are excellent and I really suggest you spend a little more time going through them.  For small apps this approach is sound and not too complex, but if your app grows, then you might want to consider looking into React Redux or the very recent React Hooks.  Both of these attempt to address the issue of passing props down through several layers of components.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when we pass data from parent, we consider it to be **Immutable**,
***(i.e)*** ***It should not be changed directly from the child components***.

So, what one could do is ***use the prop value directly from the parent*** and use a ***method to mutate or change from the parent***.

Below code is self explanatory.

**Parent**

```
class Parent {

  // parent immutable state
  public parentObject: object = {
     location: "",
     phoneNo: ""
  };

  constructor() {
    this.state = {
       parentObject: this.parentObject
    }
  }


  public onParentObjectChangeCallBack(key: string, value: string | number) {
    this.state.parentObject[key] = value;
    // to rerender
    this.setState();
  }

  public render () {
    return <ChildComponent parentObject={this.state.parentObject} 
           onChange={this.onParentObjectChangeCallBack} />
  }

}
```

**Child**

```
class ChildComponent {
  @Prop
  public parentObject: object;

  @Prop
  public onChange: Function;

  public render() {
     <div>
        {
          this.parentObject.keys.map((key) => {
            return <div>
                     <span> {{key}}</span>
                     // calls parent method to change the immutable object
                     <input value={{this.parentObject[key]}} onChange=(val) => 
                            this.onChange(key, val) />
                   </div>
          })
        }
     </div>


  }
}
```